# Useless tag: how-to

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I found a tag that looks useless: [how-to](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/how-to). There are currently only 5 questions with that tag. I think it is a useless tag because it is too general. There are currently more than 2500 questions that begin with "How do I", "How can I", "How to", and "How should I". I can't think of any legitimate uses of [how-to](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/how-to).

Comment: Agreed. The tags have been edited out. A tag with no usage will self immolate over the next couple days.